# Flash/AS3 Animating an object in an application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, movieclip

So I have an application which the user enters data and then the stuff the person enters are used in calculations which are shown to the user. To the application I am adding an animation of a rotating circle. All the objects that are used in the application are in frame 1. The rotation animation is displayed from frame 1 to lets say frame 10.

The problem is then that the objects other than the rotating circle are only visible on frame 1. I want the objects on frame 1 to be visible at all times while the circle rotates. At the same time the objects must not be altered in between frames. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks a lot you really helped me out :) EDIT: is there any reason that you commented and not  answered? new to this site...

Comment: As you wish (moved from comment to answer).  Comments are usually given when clarification is required, or the solution is too vague to be certain to resolve the issue.  Glad to see it helped, though.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Put the animation of your rotating circle into its own MovieClip.  Everything will be at frame1, and the circle will continue animating in its own "space"